# get or load data file in server

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, file-upload

i have data json, i receive json data from backend with following format.

```
{
 id: 2 
 name: file impian
 file : /home/bakcend/go/uploads/173ba017f27b69b42d7e747.png //path backend
}
```

currently a separate directory, files uploaded from the front end go to the backend folder

```
- home 
  - backend
    - go
      - uploads
      - api
```

this is the front end folder

```
- home
  - front end
    - src
      - view
      - component
      - other
```

url backend : ...8001
frontend : ...8002

just a different port

how can i load data outside the root front end ?

```
<b-img src="http://....:8001/home/backend/go/upload/173ba017f27b69b42d7e747.png"></b-img>
```

I tried it doesn't load

Answer (score 0):

You should serve static files from your backend.
Add some code to your backend for serving static files.
for example in node we can do like this:
[express.js serve static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: I will try thank you